# Content type webform template

Tags: theming, webforms

How should I name the tpl file for "training" content type webform?

I've tried webform-form-training.tpl.php and webform-training.tpl.php and it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "content type webform"? To me it sounds as if it's a regular content type, with webform functionality enabled. If that's the case, use `node--training.tpl.php`.

Comment: Yes. But I want to theme webforms for this content type. I think i can't do that in node.tpl

Comment: You can take the template(.tpl) file from webform module and put in theme’s templates folder, then you can change this one.